# How to change DAO.Recordset field type

Tags: excel, vba, dao, recordset

Is there any way how to change type of DAO.Recordset field in VBA?

For some reason interpreter evalueted recordset field as Type 8 (dateTime) but i need this field to be Text as it should be

I tried following:

```
rs.Fields(0).Type = 10
```

but this gives me *Item not found in this collection.* error.

Is there any way how can I change type of specific field in DAO.Recordset?

**Edit1:**
Here is what i've got so far

```
Private Sub doMagic()
    Dim db as DAO.Database
    Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql as String: sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Column1] IS NOT NULL"

    Set db = OpenDatabase(ThisWorkbook.FullName, False, True, "Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1;"
    set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql)

    Dim updateSQL As String: updateSQL = "ALTER TABLE [Sheet1$] ALTER COLUMN [Column5] TEXT(100)"

    ' I tried following, non of them working:
    ' db.RunSql(updateSQL) - error: Metod or data member not found
    ' db.Execute(updateSQL) - fails with error: Operation is not supported for this type of object.
    ' DoCmd.RunSql(updateSQL)- error: Object required
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to sue an `ALTER` Command. You cannot change type like that.

Comment: @PaulFrancis Can you provide me an example how to do it? I cant find any examples/documentation about this

Comment: Just Googled : **change table field structure vba access**. I got this : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822825.aspx

Comment: @PaulFrancis You can do this in SQL, but i am looking how to do it in VBA. I know how to modify table via SQL, but the thing is, that i dont know, how to do it via VBA

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a Table field type with DAO. When you create a DAO recordset, the field's definition is Read-Only. To change field type, you need to use a DDL (Data Definition Language) query, which is what the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822825.aspx) explains the SQL, which is what you normally would do. Something like,

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE yourTableName ALTER COLUMN yourColumnName TEXT(50)"
```

Comment: when i try to run this command i get an error: 424: 'Object required' it seems, that my DoCmd object is empty

Comment: Um, did you make sure you have edited the code to match your needs? Could you show the line of code you are using? Maybe update your original post?